# RXJava2 | Android: Filter arrayList and keep track of filter

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

Scenario: RXJava 2. Android.

Imagine you have an Observable from iterable like so:  `Observable.fromIterable(arrayList<Something>)` and you need to do two things with it:

1. Filter the items.
2. Know if an item was filtered out (a.k.a.: the filter function returned false at least once).

This is a similar observable (extremely simplified to be relevant):

```
    final ArrayList<Something> someArrayList = getTheArrayList();

    Observable
            .fromIterable(someArrayList)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .filter(new AppendOnlyLinkedArrayList.NonThrowingPredicate<Something>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(final Something something) {
                    return something.isValid();
                }
            })
            .toList()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSuccess(new Consumer<List<Something>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(@NonNull final List<Something> somethings) 
                    throws Exception {
                        // How can I tell if the filter above returned false
                        // at least once? 
                }
            })
            .subscribe();
```

To answer the above question, one option is to compare the original `someArrayList` to `somethings`. If they are different, well, something happened. But this means the list have to have the same items in the same order, which can be a problem if `Something` is a complicated object, that must implement an equals.

The plan B, which I am using and I don't like is to keep a "boolean array" outside the observable, like so:

`final boolean[] hasInvalidData = new boolean[1];`

and then in the `.filter` I can do:

```
    final isValid = something.isValid();
    if (!isValid) {
        hasInvalidData[0] = true;
    }
    return isValid;
```

and in success, I could simply do:

```
    if (hasInvalidData[0]) {
        // Something has been filtered
    }
```

The question is: is there a better approach?

**UPDATE**:

What I have done so far is simply compare `originalList.size()` with `finalEmitedList.size()`. If they are different, that means my filter "filtered" something.

Answer (score 2):

The way that I read it, this smells like an [XY problem](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwin--jyzI7UAhUsCMAKHSyABskQFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F66377%2Fwhat-is-the-xy-problem&usg=AFQjCNFXK9Ae-7TMNq233MZYHqOVBoKQ9g&sig2=nKIWLs_cwfdFhOFdKPvrWQ). If you *don't* need to keep track of the elements and you just need to compute until you find one element, everything becomes much easier:

```
 Observable
 .fromIterable(someArrayList)
 .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
 .map(something -> something.isValid())
 .filter(bool -> bool)
 .first(false);
```

If you actually need the list of elements:

```
 Observable<Something> source = Observable
   .fromIterable(someArrayList)
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
   .publish()
   .autoConnect(2);

source
.map(something -> something.isValid())
.reduce(false, (a,b) -> a | b)
.zipWith(source.toList(), (flag, list) -> {
   // do your stuff
})
.subscribe();
```

Comment: It could be an XY problem (I was aware of that, thanks for refreshing my memory), but… I do need to keep track of the list (at the end, that is, after it was filtered). I just need to know if an item was filtered (any). What I have done is basically, count the number of items at the end and compare if they are the same. Since the only operation is a remove (filter), the only way something the final list will contain less items is if the filter returned false. Much better than the boolean thing, but perhaps there was a better way.

Comment: Maybe you want to convert all your `Something`s to `Pair<Something, Boolean>`.

Comment: Note that as you don't have a flatMap or similar, you will compute everything sequentially.

Comment: I need the filtered list, not the filtered out items, so the final list will always be `<=` than the original

Answer (score 1):

not sure it works but **Observable.sequenceEqual** could work:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = ...
Predicate myFilter = ...
Observable<Object> observable = Observable.fromIterable(list);
Observable.sequenceEqual(observable, observable.filter(myFilter))
    .subscribe(new Consumer<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull Boolean changed) throws Exception {
            // result here
        }
    });
```